# How to use pivot to aggregate 2 columns plus some other independent columns SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a requirement to show 2 aggregate columns below a single pivoted month column. I have a record entity named 'A' and 'A' has its related records in anothe table 'AB' on the basis of ID column. 'AB' Table gives me 'Month' and 'Amount' columns. But the 2nd aggregate column 'Hours' is in another table 'CD' in which two relations are saved. 'C' has some related records from Table 'A' On the basis of a related entity.

I am using SQL Server 2014

[image: I want to show data like this]

This is my stored procedure look like :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SOWReport]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max), @stmt nvarchar(max), @year int
set @year = YEAR(GETDATE())
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#sowreport') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #sowreport;
END;

CREATE TABLE #months ([Month] [datetime] NOT NULL)
INSERT into #months([Month]) SELECT DISTINCT CAST('01 ' + b.[Month] AS datetime) AS [Date] FROM [SOW_PO] a INNER JOIN Projections b ON b.SOW_POId = a.Id WHERE b.[Month] IS NOT NULL AND  YEAR(CAST('01 ' + b.[Month] AS datetime)) = @year
SELECT @cols = (isnull(@cols + ', ', '') + '[A' + FORMAT(CAST(M.[Month] AS DateTime), N'MMMM yyyy') + ']') FROM (Select FORMAT([Month], N'MMMM yyyy') AS [Month] from #months) AS M
SELECT @cols = (isnull(@cols + ', ', '') + '[H' + FORMAT(CAST(M.[Month] AS DateTime), N'MMMM yyyy') + ']') FROM (Select FORMAT([Month], N'MMMM yyyy') AS [Month] from #months) AS M

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#months') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #months;
END;

CREATE TABLE #sowreport ([Client] [nvarchar](250) NULL, 
    [SalesRepresentative] [nvarchar](250) NULL, 
    [SOW] [bit] NULL, 
    [US] [nvarchar](20) NULL, 
    [SOWValue] [float] NULL, 
    [SOWHours] [float] NULL,
    [Task] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [PONumber] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL, 
    [EndDate] [nvarchar](250) NULL, 
    [Rate] [float] NULL,
    [ActualAmount] [float] NULL,
    [TotalAmountLeft] [float] NULL,
    [TotalHoursLeft] [float] NULL,
    [MonthActualAmount] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [MonthBilledHours] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [BilledHours] [float] NULL,
    [Month] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Month2] [nvarchar](100) NULL)

    ;WITH cte_result AS (
    SELECT b.[Month], 
    c.[ClientName] AS [Client], 
    d.[RepName] AS [SalesRepresentative], 
    a.[IsPO] AS [SOW], 
    a.[Company] as [US], 
    a.[TotalAmount] AS [SOWValue], 
    a.[TotalHours] AS [SOWHours],
    a.[Comments] AS [Task],
    ISNULL(a.[SOW_PONumberIfAny], '') AS [PONumber],
    a.[IsClosed] AS [Status],
    a.[ValidityStartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    convert(varchar(25), a.[ValidityEndDate], 120) AS [EndDate], 
    a.[Rate] AS [Rate],
    CAST(b.[Month] + ' ' + CAST(ISNULL(b.[ActualBilledAmount], 0) AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS [MonthActualAmount],
    ISNULL(b.[ActualBilledAmount], 0) AS [ActualAmount],

    CAST(b.[Month] + ' ' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(g.[BillableHours], 0)) AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS [MonthBilledHours],
    SUM(ISNULL(g.[BillableHours], 0)) AS [BilledHours]


    FROM SOW_PO a 
    JOIN Projections b ON b.SOW_POId = a.Id 
    JOIN ClientInfo c ON a.ClientId = c.Id 
    JOIN Representatives d ON a.SalesRepId = d.Id
    LEFT JOIN Invoice_SOWPO_Mapping e ON a.Id = e.SOW_POId AND e.[Month]=b.[Month]
    LEFT JOIN Invoice e1 ON e1.Id = e.InvoiceId AND e1.IsInvoiceCreated=1
    LEFT JOIN Invoice_Task_Mapping f ON e.InvoiceId = f.InvoiceId
    LEFT JOIN TaskMapping g ON f.TaskMappingId = g.Id
    GROUP BY c.[ClientName], d.[RepName], a.[IsPO], a.[Company], a.[TotalAmount], a.[TotalHours], a.[Comments], a.[SOW_PONumberIfAny], a.[IsClosed], a.[ValidityStartDate], a.[ValidityEndDate], a.[Rate], b.[Month],[ActualBilledAmount], g.[BillableHours]
    )

    --SELECT * FROM cte_result

    INSERT into #sowreport([Client],[SalesRepresentative],[SOW],[US],[SOWValue],[SOWHours],[Task],[PONumber],[Status],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Rate],[ActualAmount],[TotalAmountLeft],[TotalHoursLeft],[MonthActualAmount],[MonthBilledHours],[BilledHours],[Month],[Month2]) SELECT [Client],[SalesRepresentative],[SOW],[US],[SOWValue],[SOWHours],[Task],[PONumber],[Status],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Rate],ISNULL([ActualAmount],0),[TotalAmountLeft],[HoursLeft],[MonthActualAmount],[MonthBilledHours], [BilledHours],[Month],[Month2] FROM (

    SELECT [Client],[SalesRepresentative],[SOW],[US],[SOWValue],[SOWHours],[Task],[PONumber],[Status],[StartDate],convert(varchar(25), [EndDate], 120) AS [EndDate],[Rate],[ActualAmount], [SOWHours] - [BilledHours] AS [HoursLeft], [SOWValue] - SUM(ISNULL([ActualAmount],0)) AS [TotalAmountLeft], CAST(ISNULL([MonthActualAmount],'') AS NVARCHAR(500)) AS [MonthActualAmount],CAST(ISNULL([MonthBilledHours],'') AS NVARCHAR(500)) AS [MonthBilledHours], SUM(ISNULL([BilledHours],0)) AS [BilledHours],[Month],[Month] AS [Month2] FROM cte_result GROUP BY [BilledHours], [Client], [SalesRepresentative], [SOW], [US],[SOWValue],[SOWHours],[Task],[PONumber],[Status],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Rate],[ActualAmount],[MonthActualAmount],[MonthBilledHours],[Month]) as T

--SELECT * FROM #sowreport
--[Month],
--ISNULL([ActualAmount], 0) AS [ActualAmount]
SET @stmt = 'SELECT * FROM #sowreport AS T
PIVOT
    (
        SUM(T.[ActualAmount])
        FOR T.[Month] in (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS P1
    ORDER BY [StartDate] DESC'
exec sp_executesql  @stmt = @stmt
DROP TABLE #sowreport
END
```

But not able to get expected results. Only amount column is aggregated everytime. Below is the result i am getting

[image: Rest of the columns trimmed in below image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do any number of pivot's in the SQL statement by using the pivot keyword. I have just provided the example statement for your dynamic SQL query.

```
SET @stmt = 'SELECT * FROM #sowreport AS T
PIVOT
    (
        SUM(T.[ActualAmount])
        FOR T.[Month] in (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS P1
PIVOT
(
  SUM(T.[BilledHours])
  FOR T.[Month] in (' + @cols + ')
) AS P2
    ORDER BY [StartDate] DESC'
```

Please refer to the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/) for more examples.

Comment: I am using the same statements, but the issue is with the month columns in #sowreport.    One record is getting duplicated for each month in records.

Comment: You are getting duplicate because there will be one column that has distinct value. try to ignore that column and you wont have that issue. Can you post your full code and the table schema so that I can check it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Karthik.. I have fixed my issue by applying 2 Pivots on 2 Month Columns. One Group Of Months is For Amount and Another one is for Hours and Also need to append un-common character before All Months To Make The Difference. Thanks Again For Your Help.

Comment: If my answer has helped you please spend some time in upvoting my answer or mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Final Stored Procedure i have wrote to fix this issue after a pretty long research. The idea is to divide pivot column in such a way to differentiate them individually for both the columns.

And final work is on MVC view, where i also need to filter only 12 months from all 24 columns(12 For Amount, 12 For Hours) And Fetch Amounts and Hours accordingly.

I am sending the Controller Logic Below :

```
public ActionResult SowReport(int? pagenumber)
    {
        var modeldata = new SOW_POPivotModel();
        int currentPageIndex = pagenumber - 1 ?? 0;
        // Pivot Result Set
        **Code Where I have Fetched Stored Procedure Data Into A DataTable**
        var lstSow = objPagedList.LoadSOW_POReport(pageIndex: currentPageIndex, pageSize: 10);

        var dynamicData = new DataTable();

        if (lstSow.Count > 0)
        {
            var firstRowOnly = lstSow.FirstOrDefault();
            // Add Columns
            if (firstRowOnly != null)
                foreach (var addcol in firstRowOnly.Keys)
                {
                    dynamicData.Columns.Add(addcol.ToString());
                }

            // Add Rows
            foreach (var data in lstSow)
            {
                DataRow dr = dynamicData.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = data.Select(x => (x.Value != DBNull.Value || x.Value != null) ? x.Value : 0).ToArray();  //(row.Value == DBNull.Value || row.Value == null) ? "" : row.Value.ToString();
                dynamicData.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        var lst = new List<SOW_POPivotModel>();

        if (dynamicData.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var dynamicMonths = new List<string>();
            var firstRowOnly = lstSow.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstRowOnly != null)
                foreach (var addcol in firstRowOnly.Keys)
                {
                    if (addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "client"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "salesrepresentative"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "sow"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "us"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "sowvalue"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "sowhours"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "task"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "ponumber"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "status"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "startdate"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "enddate"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "rate"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "totalamountleft"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "totalhoursleft"
                        && addcol.Trim().ToLower().ToString() != "sowid")
                    {
                        if (dynamicMonths.All(x => x.Trim().ToLower() != addcol.Trim().Substring(1)))
                            dynamicMonths.Add(addcol.Trim().Substring(1));
                    }

                    dynamicMonths = dynamicMonths.Distinct().ToList();
                }

            foreach (var row in dynamicData.AsEnumerable())
            {
                var cell = new SOW_POPivotModel();
                cell.MonthColumnsWithAmountAndHours = dynamicMonths.Select(a => new DynamicColumnModel()
                {
                    Month = a
                }).ToList();

                cell.SOWHours = row.IsNull("SOWHours") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(row["SOWHours"]);
                cell.SOWValue = row.IsNull("SOWValue") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(row["SOWValue"].ToString());
                cell.StartDate = row.IsNull("StartDate") ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(row["StartDate"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                cell.Status = row.IsNull("Status") ? "" : row["Status"].ToString();
                cell.Task = row.IsNull("Task") ? "" : row["Task"].ToString();
                cell.TotalAmountLeft = row.IsNull("TotalAmountLeft") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(row["TotalAmountLeft"].ToString());
                cell.TotalHoursLeft = row.IsNull("TotalHoursLeft") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(row["TotalHoursLeft"].ToString());
                cell.US = row.IsNull("US") ? "" : row["US"].ToString();
                cell.SOWId = row.IsNull("SOWId") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(row["SOWId"].ToString());

                if (lst.All(x => x.SOWId != cell.SOWId))
                {
                    foreach (var monthvalue in cell.MonthColumnsWithAmountAndHours)
                    {
                        if (!row.IsNull("A" + monthvalue.Month))
                        {
                            monthvalue.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(row["A" + monthvalue.Month].ToString());
                        }

                        if (!row.IsNull("H" + monthvalue.Month))
                        {
                            monthvalue.Hours = Convert.ToDouble(row["H" + monthvalue.Month].ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    lst.Add(cell);
                }
                else
                {
                    var prevAdded = lst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SOWId == cell.SOWId);
                    if (prevAdded != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var monthvalue in prevAdded.MonthColumnsWithAmountAndHours)
                        {
                            if (!row.IsNull("A" + monthvalue.Month))
                            {
                                monthvalue.Amount += Convert.ToDouble(row["A" + monthvalue.Month].ToString());
                            }

                            if (!row.IsNull("H" + monthvalue.Month))
                            {
                                monthvalue.Hours += Convert.ToDouble(row["H" + monthvalue.Month].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var model = new SOW_POReportModel();
        model.List = lst;
        model.LoadPagedList(lstSow);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Below Is My Final Procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SOWReport]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max),@cols1 nvarchar(max), @stmt nvarchar(max), @year int
set @year = YEAR(GETDATE())

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#sowreport') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #sowreport;
END;

CREATE TABLE #months ([Month] [datetime] NOT NULL)
INSERT into #months([Month]) SELECT DISTINCT CAST('01 ' + b.[Month] AS datetime) AS [Date] FROM [SOW_PO] a INNER JOIN Projections b ON b.SOW_POId = a.Id WHERE YEAR(CAST('01 ' + b.[Month] AS datetime)) = @year
SELECT @cols = (isnull(@cols + ', ', '') + '[A' + M.[Month] + ']') FROM (Select FORMAT([Month], N'MMMM yyyy') AS [Month] from #months) AS M
SELECT @cols1 = (isnull(@cols1 + ', ', '') + '[H' + M.[Month] + ']') FROM (Select FORMAT([Month], N'MMMM yyyy') AS [Month] from #months) AS M

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#months') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #months;
END;

CREATE TABLE #sowreport ([Client] [nvarchar](250) NULL, 
    [SalesRepresentative] [nvarchar](250) NULL, 
    [SOW] [bit] NULL, 
    [US] [nvarchar](20) NULL, 
    [SOWValue] [float] NULL, 
    [SOWHours] [float] NULL,
    [Task] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [PONumber] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL, 
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL, 
    [Rate] [float] NULL,
    [ActualAmount] [float] NULL,
    [TotalAmountLeft] [float] NULL,
    [TotalHoursLeft] [float] NULL,
    [Month] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Month2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [BilledHours] [float] NULL,
    [SOWId] [int] NULL
    )

    ;WITH cte_result AS (
    SELECT a.[Id] AS [SOWId],c.[ClientName] AS [Client], 
    d.[RepName] AS [SalesRepresentative], 
    a.[IsPO] AS [SOW], 
    a.[Company] as [US], 
    a.[TotalAmount] AS [SOWValue], 
    a.[TotalHours] AS [SOWHours],
    a.[Comments] AS [Task],
    ISNULL(a.[SOW_PONumberIfAny], '') AS [PONumber],
    CASE WHEN a.[IsClosed]=1 THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'Open' END AS [Status],
    a.[ValidityStartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    a.[ValidityEndDate] AS [EndDate], 
    a.[Rate] AS [Rate],
    --ISNULL(b.[ActualBilledAmount], 0) AS [ActualAmount],
    --ISNULL(g.[BillableHours],0) AS [TotalBilledHours],
    SUM(ISNULL(b.[ActualBilledAmount], 0)) AS [ActualAmount],
    SUM(ISNULL(g.[BillableHours],0)) AS [TotalBilledHours],
    b.[Month] As [Month],
    b.[Month] As [Month2]
    FROM SOW_PO a 
    JOIN Projections b ON b.SOW_POId = a.Id 
    JOIN ClientInfo c ON a.ClientId = c.Id 
    JOIN Representatives d ON a.SalesRepId = d.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice_SOWPO_Mapping e ON e.SOW_POId = a.Id AND e.[Month] in (Select b.[Month]) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice e1 ON e1.Id = e.InvoiceId AND e1.IsInvoiceCreated=1 AND b.[Month] = e1.[Month] + ' ' + e1.[Year] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice_Task_Mapping f ON f.InvoiceId = e.InvoiceId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TaskMapping g ON g.Id in (Select f.TaskMappingId)
    GROUP BY g.[BillableHours],b.[Month],c.[ClientName],d.[RepName], a.[IsPO], a.[Company], a.[TotalAmount], a.[TotalHours], a.[Comments], a.[SOW_PONumberIfAny], a.[IsClosed], a.[ValidityStartDate], a.[ValidityEndDate], a.[Rate], b.[ActualBilledAmount],a.[Id])

    --select * from cte_result

    INSERT into #sowreport([SOWId],[Client],[SalesRepresentative],[SOW],[US],[SOWValue],[SOWHours],[Task],[PONumber],[Status],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Rate],[ActualAmount],[TotalAmountLeft],[TotalHoursLeft],[Month],[Month2],[BilledHours]) SELECT [SOWId],[Client],[SalesRepresentative],[SOW],[US],[SOWValue],[SOWHours],[Task],[PONumber],[Status],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Rate],[ActualAmount],[TotalAmountLeft],[HoursLeft],[Month],[Month2],[TotalBilledHours] FROM (
    SELECT [SOWId],[Client],[SalesRepresentative],[SOW],[US],[SOWValue],[SOWHours],[Task],[PONumber],[Status],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Rate],ISNULL([ActualAmount],0) AS [ActualAmount], [SOWHours] - [TotalBilledHours] AS [HoursLeft], [SOWValue] - SUM([ActualAmount]) AS [TotalAmountLeft],'A' + [Month] AS [Month], 'H' + [Month2] AS [Month2],[TotalBilledHours] FROM cte_result GROUP BY [Client], [SalesRepresentative], [SOW], [US],[SOWValue],[SOWHours],[Task],[PONumber],[Status],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Rate],[ActualAmount],[TotalBilledHours],[Month],[Month2],[SOWId]) as T

    --select * from #sowreport

SET @stmt = '
SELECT * FROM #sowreport AS T
PIVOT
    (
        SUM(T.[ActualAmount])
        FOR T.[Month] in (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS P
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM([BilledHours])
        FOR [Month2] in (' + @cols1 + ')
    ) AS P1
    ORDER BY [Client] ASC'
exec sp_executesql  @stmt = @stmt
DROP Table #sowreport
END
--exec SOWReport
```

And finally, View Implementation :

```
<table id="tbl-sow-report" class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="14"></th>
                        @foreach (var sowpo in Model.List)
                        {
                            foreach (var proj in sowpo.MonthColumnsWithAmountAndHours)
                            {
                                <th rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report">
                                    @proj.Month
                                </th>
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    </tr>
                    <tr role="row" id="sow-columns">
                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report" class="country">Start Date</th>
                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report" class="country">End Date</th>
                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report" class="country">Rate</th>
                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report" class="country">Total Amount Left</th>
                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report" class="country">Total Hours Left</th>
                        @foreach (var sowpo in Model.List)
                        {
                            foreach (var proj in sowpo.MonthColumnsWithAmountAndHours)
                            {
                                <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report" class="hours">Hours</th>
                                <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report" class="amt">Amount</th>
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tblRecords">
                    @foreach (var record in Model.List)
                    {
                        <tr id="@record.SOWId" role="row">
                            <td>@(record.StartDate)</td>
                            <td>@(record.EndDate)</td>
                            <td>@(record.Rate)</td>
                            <td>@(record.TotalAmountLeft)</td>
                            <td>@(record.TotalHoursLeft)</td>
                            @foreach (var proj in record.MonthColumnsWithAmountAndHours)
                            {
                                <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report">
                                    @proj.Hours
                                </td>
                                <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-controls="tbl-sow-report">
                                    @proj.Amount
                                </td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

[Final Outcome Is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkRPw.png)